# How to upload two different image with two browse button and single submit button

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to upload two images, one of the user and second of his ID, using one submit button using mysqli. Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  your image: <input type="file" name="img"><br/>
  your Id card: <input type="file" name="img2">
  <input type="submit" name="publish" value="upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

All I know is to upload the single image at a time but what if want to upload these image into the database with single submit.  I am not writing PHP because I don't know how to do this. I can upload multiple images at a time using an array but I want to use this method. Is it possible to do with PHP??

PHP for single upload:

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/";
$t_file = $dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($t_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I can upload  single image and multiple as well but not with two brose button.

Comment: when you upload a single file you'll have it in `$_FILES['img']` in your case. Where could then img2 be? [a hint from the docs](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php#89674)

Comment: Where is your problem then?

Comment: as I said that I want to upload images which can be browsed separately but can be uploaded with a single button.

Comment: @Jeff sir will you please help me.

Comment: modify your <form> tag it should be `<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: thanks @NitinSharma . This was helpful at least you gave me a right change.

Answer (score 1):

I can do it by using javascript. All respected users, please be more helpful for those who are new to any language. Or make this website only for experts, not for beginners.

So I use PHP for my first upload and JS for my second image upload.

here is js:

```
<script>
function startUpload(){
document.getElementById('uploadProcess').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.visibility = 'hidden';
return true;
}

function stopUpload(success,uploadedFile){
var result = '';
if (success == 1){
    result = '<span class="sucess-msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
    //Uploaded file preview
    var embed = document.getElementById("UploadedFile");
    var clone = embed.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('src',uploadedFile);
    embed.parentNode.replaceChild(clone,embed);
}else {
   result = '<span class="error-msg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
}
document.getElementById('uploadProcess').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('uploadForm').innerHTML = result + '<label>File:<input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" /><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';
document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.visibility = 'visible';      
return true;   
}
</script>
```

The html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="startUpload();">
 <p id="uploadForm">
 Select image to upload:
 <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
 <input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload1">
 <input type="submit" value="submitBtn" name="submit">
 </p>
</form>
```

and the upload.php:

```
<?php
$success = 0;
$uploadedFile = '';

//File upload path
$uploadPath = 'uploads/';
$targetPath = $uploadPath . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)){
    $success = 1;
    $uploadedFile = $targetPath;
}

sleep(1);
?>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
}


if ($uploadOk == 0) {
 echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```